# Stuck with "game in progress" in dota 2 beta

Tags: steam, dota-2

I was playing dota 2 beta today. A game ended and I went afk without returning to the main menu. When I returned I was at the menu with "game in progress" but no buttons to return to or leave the game. I have turned off steam, restarted dota, left steam off for a while, tried to have someone else start a group and start a new game, and tried to spectate a game. None of these things have worked.

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to the "Game is finished" message, so, there are two things you can do:

### Wait

This problem is known to vanish after some time, but the time itself is unknown.

### Spectate a game (until the end)

A more definite solution is to spectate a game until its end, and then click on the Finish Game button on the post game screen. Just watching for some time won't cut it, you have to watch until the end.

[image: Post game screen]

Comment: @Brent You're welcome! Glad to know it's fixed.